# Why is WCF generating a different proxy?

Tags: wcf

I am adding a Service Reference to a Peoplesoft WSDL.  The existing app has a proxy that was generated in a different version of .NET (4.0 I think) or svcutil.  The old proxy starts like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.235
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace PeopleSoft.CustomerService {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="CIFaultTypeShape", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/FSCM/schema/M866879.V1", ItemName="IBResponse")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
```

But the new proxy looks like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Tasks.Services.ServiceReference1 {


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/FSCM/schema/M866879.V1")]
```

Clearly the same WSDL is resulted in different proxy classes.  We have old code that relies on a FaultType (`CIFaultTypeShape`) that doesn't get generated in to the proxy class.

Is this a WCF issue that is causing that FaultType to be ignored?

Comment: Can it be that the first proxy is generated using svcutil.exe and the second one using Add Service Reference from Visual Studio? The problem might lie in a different serializer (Xml vs DataContract) being used.

Comment: Thanks, but we traced it down to a VS 2010 bug.

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same scenario (diff. between VS2008 proxy and VS2010 proxy) as this blogger did:

http://www.fransson.net/blog/cannot-access-faultexception-details/

"After some communication with Andrea Liberatore at Microsoft he engaged the Microsoft product group, and they confirmed that I had actually found a bug in Visual Studio 2010."

This makes sense, because the proxy is missing a fault type.